# Ionic - Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to do news sharing function in my ionic2 apps, and I get this code from ionic document but still showing error.

This is qq sharing, sharing with news text, image, audio, and I also want to know is it ionic got shareSdk like MOB can derictly share with all platform, bcz I have to develop fb, weibo, wechat too. Too many coding

**news.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewsDataProvider } from '../../providers/news-data/news-data';

import { QQSDK, QQShareOptions } from '@ionic-native/qqsdk';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-news-detail',
  templateUrl: 'news-detail.html',
})
export class NewsDetailPage {
    new: any;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public newsData:NewsDataProvider,
        private qq: QQSDK) {
        this.new = navParams.get('new');
  }

  share(){
    this.qq.shareText(shareTextOptions)
       .then(() => {
          console.log('shareText success');
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });

    this.qq.shareImage(options)
       .then(() => {
          console.log('shareImage success');
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });
    }

    this.qq.shareNews(options)
       .then(() => {
          console.log('shareNews success');
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });
    }

    this.qq.shareAudio(options)
       .then(() => {
          console.log('shareAudio success');
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });
      }

}
```

Here is the error in my terminal

[image]

Comment: You need to wrap your calls to `QQSDK`-methods in functions. Also you should not use the name `new` for your variable as it is a reserved word. And in order to use `options` and `shareTextOptions` you need to declare them.

Comment: I import QQSDK in this .ts file already error still coming

Comment: Yes I can see that. I didn't mention anything about importing `QQSDK` in my previous comment.